# How to obtain and manipulate QMesh vertices, faces, something else?

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I got arbitrary solid QMesh on my screen using examples. It's great. But I can to do nothing with it.  mesh->children().count = 0, mesh->primitiveCount=0, mesh->geometry()=0 and so on. How to obtain internal contents of QMesh? Can I change QMesh vertices (geometry) programmatically, on the fly? The "setSource()" does not seems sufficient for all occasions.

Comment: Can you provide some code samples so we can better see what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
Qt3DCore::QEntity * meshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity( rootEntity ); 
Qt3DRender::QMesh * mesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh(); 

QUrl url; 
url.setScheme("file"); 
url.setPath("/tmp/trefoil.obj");
mesh->setSource( url ); 

// now i print some of properties. 
qDebug() << mesh->geometry() << ", children nodes=" << mesh->childrenNodes().count(); 
// ... children... primitiveCount... and so on. I see only empty values.
```

Comment: I wonder something similar to mesh->getVertices(), mesh->getBones(), getFacets()... and so on. Any form of geometrical descriptions of the body (solid) within the mesh.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you manage to do it please?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Instead of that, I used the assimp library and QOpenGLWindow-based visualization.

Comment: OK :(. Thanks anyway!